# installing on a physical drive with virtualbox/Windows

Tags: windows, virtualbox

How can I install a guest system on a physical drive/partition in virtualbox running on a Windows host ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To use a physical disk drive directly in Virtualbox you need to first create a special vmdk file to reference the physical drive and then assign the vmdk file as a drive to your VM. Section 9.5.1.1 of the [VirtualBox user manual](http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/UserManual.pdf) shows how to create the vmdk file. More info here: http://agnipulse.com/2009/07/boot-your-usb-drive-in-virtualbox/

Comment: Great! I didn't know this was possible! +1

Answer (score 2):

This section provided all info I needed to do this

http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch09.html#rawdisk